# how to get back to loop after this if?

Tags: java

would you please help me on this?
I have written an class  and here is the code. I have two problems.

(1) I wanted to know how to get back to the beginning of the loop after user has enter copies he wants to add instead of exiting the system. I mean after system says "copies has been added." it ask user "if you want to add a book?" and then loop start again.

(2) What should I do to add an object to the array each time loop is finished?
my problem is everytime loop is running, the book1 is being rewritten. 
 thank guys- solved

Comment: You should be careful when using `nextInt` and `nextLine`.. Remember that `nextInt` reads only the integer value, the new line char will be read in the `nextLine`.

Comment: If you want re-run the loop once more after add a copy, are you sure for is a good choice ? Maybe you should use a while loop and increment m variable when needed

Comment: Why do you have a `System.exit(0);` there?

Comment: to exit, but i want to change it to a loop instead

Comment: Anyways, just as an advice, use methods, this way the code is more readable, also for you. It would be easer to model logic of your program and see what your loops are doing. But again this is just an advice

Comment: thanks mate, can you tell me how to change for (int m=0;m<10;m++) to a while-do? I don't know where to put {}

Comment: I changed it to a do-while but still it overwrite book1 each time loop repeats

Comment: this method is far too long. You should split it in small understandable methods. It will also help you to re-call some parts more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, this will make your loop run until the user enters yes

```
System.out.println("do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) ");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String h = s.nextLine();
while (h.contains("yes")|| h.compareToIgnoreCase("YES") == 0) {
int size=list.size();
//your code here
System.out.println("do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) ");
h = s.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: nice, but the problem is, loop always continue with this coding, it never ask the question again! I tried it and once user enter yes the loop repeat forever

Comment: James b did you remember to ask for the Yes\No user input again at the end of your do?

Comment: @jamesb.. that was good catch. I changed it to a while loop instead of do-while. This one suites your requirement

Comment: this time, it ends the loop first time without waiting for the answer!

Comment: the following book has been added
title : a
Author : a
Edition number: 2
ISBN : 123
Number of copies : 2



do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

Comment: r u sure you added this line before the loop ends ? h = s.nextLine();

Comment: yess, System.out.println("do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) ");
  h = s.nextLine();

Comment: it has to be s.next() instead of s.nextLine().

Comment: G V , still it doesn't create multiple book1 and add to list, it just overwrite book1 everytime. any solution?

Comment: tell me how are you traversing that list to read books. Rightnow it is clear that it is adding books to the list

Comment: here is my execution example: do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
yes
Please enter Book ISBN number
123
ISBN number has been added
.
the following book has been added
title : a
ISBN : 123
.
do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
yes
Please enter Book ISBN number
4444
ISBN number has been added
Please Enter Book's Title
a
.
the following book has been added
title : a
ISBN : 4444
Number of copies : 4
do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
yes
Please enter Book ISBN number
123
ISBN number has been added
Please Enter Book's Title

Comment: see it doesn't recognize ISBN 123 in third attemp

Comment: it must say the book already exist and ask user how many copies to ask

Comment: when I use loop only once it works : do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
yes
Please enter Book ISBN number
123
ISBN number has been added
Please Enter Book's Title
a
.
title : a
Author : a
Edition number: 1
ISBN : 123
Number of copies : 1



do you want to add a Book?(yes or no) 
yes
Please enter Book ISBN number
123
The Boook Exists,and  1 copies are available
How many copies you want to add?
5
5 copies has been added. the book has 6 copies now.
Thank you for using System

Comment: put the size variable inside loop.. You are either traversing through the first 3 elements.. or the last element (in the second if). So when you added 123, 444 it didn't search for 123 as it was 4th element.

Comment: how to put size variable inside my loop? in first if, I've put  while (x<size) so each time it add a book to list it also increment the size doesn't it? it remains 3?

Comment: I though each time it increment the list size!

Comment: yes.. and getting the size in loop enables you to loop over the incremented list

Comment: Oh, I put int x=list.size before the loop!

Comment: c'mon just put int size = list.size() inside the loop

Comment: already did it, same result, even added size++ at the end, not working :(

Comment: I don't know what ur current code is. Did you put x=list.size.. its not required. keep it to 0 and keep it inside the loop

Comment: it's solved man! the point was "Book book1=new Book();" has to be inside loop to work!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for (int m=0;m<10;m++)` with a do-while loop

Declare `Book book1=new Book();` at the top instead of inside the loop

Comment: thank guys, for do-while, I have to put all codes to {} after do?

Comment: how can I change to do a do-while?

Comment: yes.. whatever is in for loop now. Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: it says empty statement after while

Comment: I changed it to a do-while but still it overwrite book1 each time loop repeats

Comment: It is not overriding book1, but creating a new book everytime and adding it to the list.

Comment: but why when I create 2 books and then I enter ISPN of first book it doesn't find it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Branching statements would help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok to restart the loop there is a keyword `continue`

Comment: when I change for to do-while I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException